# Static navigation when header scrolled out of page. Making this work with scaleable content. Any tips?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My first post here and I have stumbled upon a bit of a problem here. This works when window is at full size (1024px), but when content scales down, the image (header) will naturally have a height lesser than 180px..

So, my question is as follows: Is there a way to make jQuery know the exact height of header-image at any time?

CSS

```
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    height: 1024px;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.headerLogo
{
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
}

.headerLogo img
{
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.meny
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    height: 50px;

    display: block;
    float: left;

    /*opacity: 0.8;*/

    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
.fastMeny
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 180)
    {
        $(".meny").addClass("fastMeny");
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 180)
    {
        $(".meny").removeClass("fastMeny");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to programatically retrieve the height of the image:

```
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function()
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var $window = $(window), 
            $img = $('.headerLogo'),
            $meny = $('.meny');

        if ($window.scrollTop() > $img.height()) {
            $meny.addClass("fastMeny");
        }
        else if ($window.scrollTop() < $img.height()) {
            $meny.removeClass("fastMeny");
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

Also note that handlers attached to the `scroll` event can kill performance. I added a timeout so that your code is only run 50ms after scrolling has stopped. This should prevent any performance issues on scroll.

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort. I have one more question. How do i point to the specific image in this jquery? @Rory McCrossan

Comment: You need to change the `$('.headerLogo')` selector to fit the code you have.